# Не удается перерисовка View в andoid

Tags: android, view

Ребят, подскажите пожалуйста как в данном коде вызывать перерисовку, инвалидате не работает, нужно перерисовку вызывать перед каждым рисованием и желательно в потоке рисования, вот код

```
public class DrawView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

        private DrawThread drawThread;

        public DrawView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            getHolder().addCallback(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                                   int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            drawThread = new DrawThread(getHolder());
            drawThread.setRunning(true);
            drawThread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            boolean retry = true;
            drawThread.setRunning(false);
            while (retry) {
                try {
                    drawThread.join();
                    retry = false;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }

        class DrawThread extends Thread {

            private boolean running = false;
            private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
            Paint paint = new Paint();

            public DrawThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
                paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            }

            public void setRunning(boolean running) {
                this.running = running;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {

                Canvas canvas;
                while (running) {
                    canvas = null;

                    try {
                        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                        if (canvas == null)
                            continue;
                       // canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
                        if (drawingRect) {

                            canvas.drawRect(a1,a2,b+20,b1+20,paint);
                            System.out.println("Risuem "+a1+" "+a2+" "+b+" "+b1);

                        }
                    } finally {
                        if (canvas != null) {

                            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Здесь много, что можно... и нужно переписать для корректной работы. Для того, чтоб просто отрисовалась фигура. Достаточно поправить немного, в run, попробуйте так:

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas canvas;
        while (running) {
            canvas = null;
            try {
                canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                if (canvas != null) canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200, paint);
                System.out.println("Risuem...");

            } finally {
                if (canvas != null) {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

В теории в верхнем левом углу нарисуется квадрат, 200х200px, цвета CYAN.